# Hibernate one os and boot to another

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, hibernate

Hi i have a setup like this:

Windows:
SSD Drive - there is everything that the Windows uses (partition, boot manager etc)
HDD Drive 500 gb - 400gb partition that Windows is using.

HDD Drive 100gb of 500gb - I have linux here, /root , /home /boot /swap partition.

Can I safely hibernate windows and boot to windows or other way around - hibernate linux and boot to windows? I am not that advanced in this matter and after reading some answers here I still can't tell for myself. Can you help me out?

Comment: If you want to access ***any*** files in one system from the other such as a document on your Windows partition from Ubuntu then the answer is **NO**.  Doing so can cause corruption.

Comment: If you absolutely never have any common partitions between the two hibernated OSes then there is a good chance you are fine.